# Helm + Umbrella Charts + Azure Pipeline

Tags: microservices, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm

I'm new to Helm, microservices and Kubernetes. For the past couple months I was working on a PoC and now  I'm trying to setup a pipeline in Azure DevOps for deploying a chart that I'm currently upgrading manually.
Currently I have an umbrella chart for defining among other things, each microservice as a requirement (requirements.yaml):

```
dependencies:  
  - name: serviceA
    version: 0.1.0
    repository: "file://../serviceA/charts/serviceA"
  - name: serviceB
    version: 0.1.1
    repository: "file://../serviceB/charts/serviceB"
```

For each microservice, I have a value.yaml where I define the image and the repo like this:

```
image:
  repository: myacr.azurecr.io/serviceA
  tag: 8ca05e4
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

So far I was upgrading the deployment in this way:

```
 - Build and push Docker Images to ACR
 - Foreach microservice chart, bump the Chart version and update the Image Tag
 - Update the microservice version in the Umbrella chart
 - Finally to deploy the solution:

helm dep update
helm dep build
helm upgrade ....
```

Since I'm learning my way into Helm and Kubernetes, I might not have taken the best decisions.
However, this setup gives me what I currently need, a way to update only what has changed.

Now I'm trying to move this manual process to a pipeline in Azure DevOps.
I'm using a single repository for the services A & B.

So far what I was able to do in the pipeline is to build and push each service image to ACR (if something changed). I'm using the commit hash for tagging the images.

Finally, here are my questions or if someone would have some advise on how should I:

1. How can I bump each microservice chart version?
2. How can I update the image tag for each chart?
3. How can I bump the versions in the umbrella chart?

Any help or advise would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do a workaround in your pipeline to update the **image tag** and **chart version** using the YAML processor `yq`. Please go through https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

Ex:

1. `yq w -i serviceA/Chart.yaml version <version>`
2. `yq w -i serviceA/values.yaml image.tag <image-tag-name>`
3. `yq w -i parentChart/Chart.yaml version <version>`

However, the Chart version must follow the *SemVer 2 standard*.